# Corresponding arrays with buttons

Tags: python, arrays, button, tkinter, sudoku

I am making a Sudoku Grid, and i have managed to generate a 9x9 grid of buttons.
I have also created an array which holds 81 values.
Is there anyway in which i could get the values inside the buttons to match their relevant index in the array. I only want a few of the numbers to show, maybe around 3 on each row? Any ideas!?

Heres the button generator:

```
#Create a 9x9 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
for row_index in range(9):
    for col_index in range(9):
        if (row_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8} and col_index in {3, 4, 5}) or \
                (row_index in {3, 4, 5} and col_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8}): #Colours a group of 3x3 buttons together to differentiate the board better.
            colour = 'gray85'
        else:
            colour = 'snow'
        c=True
        btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour) #create a button inside frame 
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
        buttons.append(btn)
```

Here's the array of values:

```
    easy = [
 [8,5,1,9,4,3,6,7,2],
 [4,3,9,6,7,2,5,1,8],
 [6,7,2,1,8,5,9,3,4],
 [1,2,3,7,9,4,8,6,5],
 [7,6,5,2,1,8,4,9,3],
 [9,4,8,3,5,6,7,2,1],
 [5,9,6,4,2,1,3,8,7],
 [2,8,7,5,3,9,1,4,6],
 [3,1,4,8,6,7,2,5,9],
]
```

I have played with the ideas of enumerate, however haven't come to any success with this.

```
def Enumerate():
    for row_index in enumerate(easy):
        for col_index in enumerate(row_index):
            for btn in buttons:
                btn.config(text=col_index)
```

When i run the enumerate function, the following gets displayed.
https://gyazo.com/1aeba588e321b5228e2d50d68ab24583

For the text of each button it outputs the final list in the array. I feel it has something to do with the loops around the enumerate, however i'm not sure any other ways in which i could perform this task then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Enumerate() function has issues:

1. enumerate returns a tuple on every iteration.  That tuple consists of the index in the iterable(list) and then the list item at that index.  This means your second for statement is not iterating over each row of data in the list, but over the tuple of (index, list).
2. You iterate through and process the entire buttons list for every iteration through the col_index loop.

try this function instead:

```
def populate():
    for row_index, row_data in enumerate(easy):
        for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):
            buttons[(row_index * 9) + col_index].config(text=cell_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would assigning the text to the button at creation make sense? For example,

```
button_text = str(easy[row_index][col_index])
btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour, text=button_text)
```

Comment: This works yes. However i intend to add difficulty levels. How could i make it so this changes depending on the difficulty level selected (please bear in mind the difficulty level is selected on the menu bar at the top, therefore when easy is slected i wish for these numbers to generate)

Comment: Presumably you'll have other nested lists such as *hard*, which contain different data. Just write a function that uses similar range for-loops as you did when creating the buttons, use the different list to get the button text, and this time just configure the button text `button.configure(text=<new text>)`.

Comment: I cannot use button.configure though. It is not recognisable outside of the button generator loop. Ive had this issue before. Any suggestions?

Comment: You defined buttons as a list, I see that from `buttons.append(btn)`. You either have to make buttons global or a class variable. If a class variable, then all of your methods in the same class will be able to access self.buttons. If you make it global, just use the `global buttons` statement at the top of your functions that use it.